# how to set precision and scale for decimal type in core data?

Tags: core-data, nsdecimalnumber

Do you know how can I set precision and scale for decimal type properly?

I can choose decimal type for attribute, but I cannot see where to setup precision and scale.

Is it possible to add some pure sql queries altering table during migration (to set DECIMAL(scale, precision))? Or should I just create NSDecimalNumber with mantissa and exponent based on wanted scale and precision (that means I would have to calculate everything by myself and I'm not sure what is happening on database site)

thanks in advance, Ania